# iPhone UIWebView intercept HTTP calls to redirect through proxy

Tags: iphone, ios, proxy, asihttprequest

I'm trying to hook UIWebView so that when a user enters a url, they are re-directed through our proxy and prompted for authentication.

I'm essentially needing to take the request and add proxy information to the request and pass it over to a UIWebView.

The proxy has to be controlled by the iOS application and not by safari or read from system wide credentials.

I've tried using ASIHTTPRequest to create a request to route through a known proxy with NTLM authentication, that works fine however doesn't bring back css, javascript, images etc.

I then read about and used ASIWebPageRequest however that is currently a bit unstable, doesn't stream and waits for the whole HTML site to download before rendering it to the user.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to change the content of the pages so that they point directly to your proxy? That might work.

Personally I'm very curious if there is any other way to do this without rewriting URLs (basically w/ only client side changes). If you found a solution please let me know1